# Random Spacing Between Div & Anchor Tags

Tags: html, css, anchor, spacing, divider

I am attempting to make a button, with a green background, an image, and text, all which should be clickable to take you to the same destination.

I am unsure how to do this, but at its current point, it works. It looks a bit confusing though, and I'm using the same class twice, which I know you shouldn't do, but I have been unable to find a solution.

The answer I am looking for is to minimize the space between the image and the text, while still getting everything to work as described above. It may have to do with the `div` tags, but when I change anyhting, none of it works.

```css
.takecoverbutton {
  width: 759px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.takecoverimage {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.buttonpara {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="takecoverbutton" align="center">
  <a href="takecover.html">
    <div class="takecoverbutton" align="center">
      <div class="takecoverimage">
        <img src="images/takeCoveriCon.jpg">
      </div>
      <p class="buttonpara">1. Take Cover</p>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your div ending tags.... there is extra closing div tag

Comment: Also your text has got a `margin` of 60px, so set that to what you want, and it will work :)

Comment: Here's a working JSFiddle I created for you - I also neatened up your code ;) 
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: also the align attribute isn't valid, use css instead

Answer (score 0):

Browser by default adds some margin to the paragraph. you need to remove the margin.

Your `.buttonpara` is having margin remove margin add this css  `margin-top:0px;`

```
.buttonpara {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-top:0px;
 }
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.takecoverbutton {
  width: 759px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.takecoverimage {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.buttonpara {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="takecoverbutton" align="center">
  <a href="takecover.html">
    <div class="takecoverbutton" align="center">
      <div class="takecoverimage">
        <img src="images/takeCoveriCon.jpg">
      </div>
      <p class="buttonpara">1. Take Cover</p>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    `<div></div>` instead of `<p></p>`

```css
.takecoverbutton {
  width: 759px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.takecoverimage {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.buttonpara {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="takecoverbutton" align="center">
  <a href="takecover.html">
    <div class="takecoverbutton" align="center">
      <div class="takecoverimage">
        <img src="images/takeCoveriCon.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="buttonpara">1. Take Cover</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## In your `.paratext` just set the margin to zero: `margin: 0;`

That's it - you were nearly there :)

By default the browser adds in some stylings to some elements, including a margin for the p tags. You could either override this, or just use a span instead.

(I've neatened up your code for you, see below)

```css
.take-cover-button {
  width: 759px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.take-cover-image {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.take-cover-text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="take-cover-button">
  <a href="takecover.html">
        <img class="take-cover-image" src="http://placehold.it/100x50">
        <p class="take-cover-text">1. Take Cover</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

The changes I implemented were:

- Fixed incorrect nesting
- Clearer class names
- Removed obsolete html attributes (like `align`)
- Removed unnecessary extra div's

Should make your code easier to manage and debug.

For future reference, when your trying to debug something like that - try using the browser developer tools <kbd>F12</kbd>. You can use the inspector to view exactly which elements are causing spacing issues, and adjust the padding, margin or any other CSS property strait from your browser. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a margin on your p tags